# customize the get_payload function in django-graphql-jwt

Tags: django, graphql, django-graphql-jwt

please, how can I customise the [get_payload](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt/blob/master/graphql_jwt/utils.py#L84) function in [django-graphql-jwt](https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-jwt)?

```
def get_payload(token, context=None):
    try:
        payload = jwt_settings.JWT_DECODE_HANDLER(token, context)
    except jwt.ExpiredSignature:
        raise exceptions.JSONWebTokenExpired()
    except jwt.DecodeError:
        raise exceptions.JSONWebTokenError(_('Error decoding signature'))
    except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
        raise exceptions.JSONWebTokenError(_('Invalid token'))
    return payload
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution that I did for the moment:

I added this `JWT_DECODE_HANDLER` setting to `GRAPHQL_JWT`:

```
    GRAPHQL_JWT = {
        'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER': 'path_to_your_customized_jwt_decode',
    }
```

than here is my `customized_jwt_decode` function:

```py
from graphql_jwt.utils import jwt_decode

def customized_jwt_decode(token, context=None):
    try:
        payload = jwt_decode(token, context)
    except YourExceptionHere:
        # that ever you wanna do 
    return payload
```